# Formatting multiple dataframes with a function returning the correct output but then recalling the old variable

Tags: python, pandas, function

I keep running into this issue and have not been able to find a solution. I have 10 separate dataframes and am trying to use one function to format all of them at once. When running the function in Jupyter Notebook, it shows me that the correct formatting takes place by showing the correctly formatted last dataframe (df10, odds_sb). However, when I call what should be one of the newly formatted dataframes again, what is returned is the old format.

```
#Create function to format odds dataframes
def format_odds(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10):
    for idx, df in enumerate((df1, df2, df3, df4, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10)):
        df = df.T
        df = df.add_suffix(idx)
    return df

# Run format odds function to transpose and add number to each column
# This shows that they were correctly formatted
format_odds(odds_opening, odds_bovada, odds_betonline, odds_intertops, odds_sbtng, 
            odds_betnow, odds_gtbets, odds_skybook, odds_5dimes, odds_sb)

#Back to old formatting for some reason
odds_opening
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your returned values are not getting assigned back. That might be the issue. Also not sure if this is the right way to use a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a temp table and add each df to it.. also you have to call the enumerate on a list...
Please note that when you add suffix the column names will be different and the append will not add rows but columns. But anyways the following code will demonstrate the idea of how to append data frames with the same format (same columns count/names/type)

```
def format_odds(df1, df2, df3):
    res = pd.DataFrame()
    for idx, df in enumerate([df1, df2]):
        df = df.T
        df = df.add_suffix(idx)
        res = res.append(df)
    return res
```

Comment: Thanks! I then converted the objects to floats and then reset and grouped by the index taking the max value to get rid of the redundant rows and removing the nans. I appreciate your help